# Is it possible to combine overlapping polygons and preserve holes?

Tags: turfjs

I have two geojson files (below). The polygon defined in poly_b contains a hole and is contained within the polygon defined by poly_a.

What I would like to do is merge these two polygons together, but preserve the hole in poly_b.

How can I do that using turf?

I tried using the union function in turf, but that returned poly_a, which I can see would be expected.

poly_a

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[0,0],[0,50],[50,50],[50,0],[0,0]]],"type":"Polygon"},"properties":{"ISO_A3_EH":"_MASK_"},"type":"Feature"}]}
```

poly_b

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[10,10],[10,40],[40,40],[40,10],[10,10]],[[20,20],[20,30],[30,30],[30,20],[20,20]]],"type":"Polygon"},"properties":{"ISO_A3_EH":"_MASK_"},"type":"Feature"}]}
```